# Decreasing performance of ASP Core on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, memory, cpu-usage

*After some extensive troubleshooting, I'm making dramatic edits to this question. The underlying issue is the same, but I managed to repro separately, making less relevant some of my concerns from before.*

I'm in the process of migrating a high-performance ASP Core 3.1 site from Azure Web Apps to DigitalOcean Kubernetes. I'm working on two Linux deployments right now.

In one of thsoe two deployments (the more heavily-trafficked one), I'm seeing requests take an increasing amount of time, right up until they start to time out. For Kubernetes, my liveness probe then kills the container, leaving performance times like this:

[image: Request response time]

In my original draft, I incorrectly boiled the problem down to the way Kubernetes was talking to memory, because memory pressure appeared to be climbing alongside the response time, and I suspected paging issues when paired with an also-increasing CPU, which didn't seem to reproduce anywhere else.

But *now,* I've managed to get the issue to reproduce on vanilla Linux, which it didn't before. I'm not sure what changed, as I'm still using the same deployment. But I'm not going to complain, as this should help make it easier to troubleshoot.

That brings us to `htop`. I'm not sure whether this is weird or not, but the process seems to be spinning up a lot of threads. It seems to level off at 4,900 after several minutes of execution.

Around the time it hits that many threads, failures start. App Insights tells me it's a `System.OutOfMemoryException` in `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ScheduleAndStart`.

Memory, meanwhile, may or may not be interesting. Actual used RAM stays between 800-1,000 MB, which is a lot, but it's in-line with what I see locally. The server has 8 GB of RAM, so that's fine.

But virtual memory is huge. I figure it's *probably* nothing, and virtual memory can be misleading, but it climbs to 43.7 GB. I'm assuming that's a consequence of the high task count.

CPU seems to spend its time 50/50 between two states. First, all four cores hang out between 0-10%, with maybe some spikes, but nothing wild. That's what I'd expect.

But then suddenly all four cores get pegged up at 100% for a few (10-20) seconds.

The issue seems to be exceedingly similar to [an issue on CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/25645) that turned out to be caused by poor lifecycle management, but having looked quite a bit, I'm not able to find anything (nor can the Roslyn analyzers)

I'm just hitting wall after wall here. What else can I try to work on narrowing down the issue?

---

Some environment information:

- Environment: DigitalOcean droplet
- Node size: 4 vCPU, 8 GB RAM (single node cluster)
- ASP Core 3.1.100
- Request timing rises for all types, including SignalR and regular MVC API
- Dependency response time is constant (and low)

Comment: Docker container on its own doesn't limit on memory. While kubernetes limit memory usage of container which are defined by resources.limits. Do you see same memory usage on docker container, as in does it continously grow?  Kubernetes resets a pod if it repeatedly crossed memory limit.

Comment: @Sham332 I didn't notice any memory issues on the vanilla Docker, although I wasn't really looking. But the performance never degraded, so I have to think the issue wasn't there. Kubernetes also wasn't killing it until I set the liveness probe.

Comment: How do you use Kubernetes? AKS?

Comment: @ZakiMa DigitalOcean offers it as a [hosted service](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/). I'm using that.

Comment: Do you use Azure Monitor Container Insights (it can work with non-Azure Kubernetes services)? Or only Application Insights?

Comment: @ZakiMa Only App Insights, since I've been using it for the service all along. Do you think it'll lend meaningful insights on top of what I'm already looking at? I can get it set up, but it looks like not the most trivial thing to do. But I'll try it if you think it's worthwhile. I've been thinking of getting Prometheus set up, but haven't done that yet.

Comment: I should add: DigitalOcean offers a bit of rudimentary monitoring out-of-box, which is where the "Memory usage" and "CPU usage" charts came from. I figured that was pretty much everything I could expect to get of any service, but as I say, I'm happy to try more if you think it'll lend insight.

Comment: For a .Net Core App running in Kubernetes, memory collected by AI SDK is private memory in bytes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/WEB/Src/PerformanceCollector/Perf.Shared.NetStandard20/XPlatProcessMemoryPerformanceCounter.cs#L21

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a very long startup time (5 mins). There is no readiness probe, which means your container could be getting requests even before it is fully ready to serve requests. Do you know why you expect 5 mins startup and also why you dont have radiness probe?

Comment: I'd recommend posting this as a comment and deleting the answer, as it does not directly answer the question. That said, the server is able to respond within 40 ms for the first several requests, so it doesn't seem like a startup timing issue. Something makes successful responses progressively slower over time. I see where you're going with the line of thinking, but I think there's evidence against it.